# error en mi codigo: no match for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++

//Ecuacion del movimiento rectilineo uniformemente acelerado.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

    main(){

    float s, Vo, t, So, a, S;
    cout<<"Ingrese el desplazamiento en el tiempo (m): ";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"Ingrese la Velocidad inicial (m/s): ";
    cin>>Vo;
    cout<<"Ingrese el Tiempo (s): ";
    cin>>t;
    cout>>"Ingrese el desplazamiento inicial (m): ";
    cin>>So;
    cout>>"Ingrese la aceleracion (m/s2): ";
    cin>>a;
    S=(So+Vo*t)+(1/2*a*t);
     cout<<"El resultado es: "<<S<<endl;

     system("pause");
     return 0;

    }
```

> 16    6[Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka > std::basic_ostream}' and 'const char [40]')
>   cout>>"Ingrese el desplazamiento inicial (m): ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes los dos últimos `cout` con el operador mal puesto `>>`